# Combine chained rewrite rule to remove all trailing slashes

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I'm using this rule to remove all trailing slashes:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/////////$ $1 [N]
RewriteRule ^(.*)////////$ $1 [N]
RewriteRule ^(.*)///////$ $1 [N]
RewriteRule ^(.*)//////$ $1 [N]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/////$ $1 [N]
RewriteRule ^(.*)////$ $1 [N]
RewriteRule ^(.*)///$ $1 [N]
RewriteRule ^(.*)//$ $1 [N]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

But the 301 header does only get sent when the last rule is hit. I don't get these rules combined and working.

This `RewriteRule ^(.*)/+$ $1 [R=301,L]` does NOT work, it looks like it is but it generates a rewrite loop. I need all slashes removed at once...

Answer (score 1):

I would rather fix the source of the extra slashes than use this kind of redirect-kludge to avoid problems with it.

However, this is the rule that does what you want:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/+$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

Instead of using .* (0 or more instances of any character, use "any character but /" character class. This way the (.*) part won't match any / part of the original URL, causing the redirect loop.

Comment: If the URL is `http://example.com/test/page/site/////////////////`, does this still match the `/` in the middle of the url?

Comment: True, it won't work for that URL. Can't you fix the piece of software that generates the invalid URLs?

Comment: There is no invalid URL, this rule is used to prevent and capture wrong generated urls by 3rd party companies.